# jconsole GUI not showing on OSX

Tags: java, jconsole

I am using adoptopenjdk8 and trying to launch the jconsole GUI to attach to my java application.

I am running the jconsole like so

```
MBROWN-MBP:~ mark$ which jconsole
/usr/bin/jconsole
MBROWN-MBP:~ mark$ jconsole -debug
```

This causes the application to open in the dock, but no GUI is opened so I cannot connect to my Java process.

I don't see any logs or output for the debug option to hint at what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a cheesy workaround, but I don't know why this vanishing situation happens ... and want to know a real solution. If I use multiple monitors, I get the same situation - looks like it's launched on the dock, but it does not appear.

**Workaround:**
If I remove the monitor connections and launch JConsole, the JConsole window appears. From there, I then reattach the monitors and use JConsole. This workaround isn't ideal and is time consuming, but it's possible to use JConsole.

Comment: Yes, it seems my issue was the same! Realised some time later when I was working without my monitors connected, *facepalm*

Comment: Still ... seems like there should be a better solution such either fixing this bug or a way to start the java VM with a specific parameter.